# several timing functions for the same animation

Tags: css

Can I put several timing functions for the same animation..

```
div{  
width:100px;  
height:100px;  
background:red;  
position:relative;  
animation:mymove 3s;  
animation-iteration-count:2;  
animation-timing-function: ease;}  

@keyframes mymove{ 
0% {top:0px;}  
25% {top:100px;}  
100% {top:200px;}}
```

I want it to *ease* from 0% to 25% and *ease-out* from 25% to 100%

Answer (score 0):

You can define a uniqe value with `animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(n,n,n,n);`

This site helps you customizing it: http://cubic-bezier.com/

Answer (score 0):

it needs to be in side your animation:

```
@keyframes mymove{ 
0% {top:0px;}  
25% {top:200px;}  
100% {top:0px;}
}
```

is this what looked for ?
or

```
@keyframes mymove{ 
0% {top:0px;} 
6.25% {top:100px;}
25% {top:200px;}  
100% {top:200px;}
}
```

you can use steps  bezier curve : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function
or play with it:

http://cubic-bezier.com

http://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/

Comment: No, I want the animation to start with *ease* and when its 25% I want it to start another timing function, like: ease-out.

Comment: so use steps or bezier curve, whatever you like to call them that's what they are meant for, just follow the links given and read :)